# Java Error - array required, but java.lang.String found

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I've been working on this problem for a while and managed to get rid of almost all the errors on this program. Every time I compile I seem to get this error saying "array required, but java.lang.String found." I'm really confused on what this means. Can someone help me please? I've been struggling a lot.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Period
{
  private static String phrase;
  private static String alphabet;
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    int[] letter = new int [27];
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence with a period at the end.");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    userInput.toLowerCase();
  }

  public void Sorter(String newPhrase)
  {
    phrase=newPhrase.substring(0,newPhrase.indexOf("."));
  }

  private int charToInt(char currentLetter)
  {
    int converted=(int)currentLetter-(int)'a';
    return converted;
  }

  private void writeToArray()
  {
    char next;
    for (int i=0;i<phrase.length();i++)
    {
      next=(char)phrase.charAt(i);
      sort(next);
    }
  }

  private String cutPhrase()
  {
    phrase=phrase.substring(0,phrase.indexOf("."));
    return phrase;
  }

  private void sort(char toArray)
  {
    int placement=charToInt(toArray);
    if (placement<0)
    {
      alphabet[26]=1; // This is here the error occurs.
    }
    else
    {
      alphabet[placement] = alphabet[placement] + 1; // This is where the error occurs.
    }
  }

  public void entryPoint()
  {
    writeToArray();
    displaySorted();
  }

  private void displaySorted()
  {
    for (int q=0; q<26;q++)
    {
      System.out.println("Number of " + (char)('a'+q) +"'s: "+alphabet[q]); //this is where the error occurs.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: as the error says `String alphabet` is a `String`, but by accessing it with an index `alphabet[26]` you are trying to access the `String` as it where an array.

Comment: @KevinEsche oh ok I see what you mean. How would I get rid of the error? Would I have to change it into an array or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
private static String alphabet;
```

with

```
private static char[] alphabet = new char [27];//to keep it in sync with letter
```

it should work.

Comment: I don't think that would work with my program because later on I have "alphabet[26] = 1" and I think you're not able to change an "int" into a char.

Comment: Sorry I meant I have "alphabet[placement] = alphabet[placement] +1" @PrinceManiGupta

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `String` as an array. There are two options here to fix this:

1) Make `alphabet` `char[]` instead of `String`.

- or

2) Don't treat `alphabet` like an array. Instead of trying to reference a character as if it was stored in an array, use `alphabet.charAt(placement)`. You can't use `charAt()` to replace one character with another, though, so instead of:

```
alphabet[placement] = alphabet[placement] + 1;
```

use this:

```
alphabet = alphabet.substring(0, placement+1) + "1" + alphabet.substring(placement+1);
```

That's assuming you want to insert "1" after the specified character in `alphabet` (it isn't entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve here). If you meant instead to have that line of code replace the character you've referred to as `alphabet[placement]` with the one that follows it, you would want to do this instead:

```
alphabet = alphabet.substring(0, placement+1) + alphabet.charAt(placement+1) + alphabet.substring(placement+1);
```

Alternatively, you could set `alphabet` to be a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String` to make it easier to modify. If `alphabet` is a `StringBuilder`, then the first alternative to the line in question (inserting "1") could be written like this:

```
alphabet = alphabet.insert(placement, 1);
```

The second alternative (changing `alphabet.charAt(placement)` to match the following character could be written like this:

```
alphabet.setCharAt(placement, alphabet.charAt(placement+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you cannot threat String in java like an array (e.g., alphabet[i]).

String are immutable in Java. You can't change them.

You need to create a new string with the character replaced.

```
String myName = "domanokz";
String newName = myName.substring(0,4)+'x'+myName.substring(5);
```

Or you can use a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("domanokz");
myName.setCharAt(4, 'x');

System.out.println(myName);
```

If I were you, I would have used the second method.